# why ng-show didn't work correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show or hide the div using **ng-show or ng-hide**.I have two button on click of first (**showTable**)I show table and on click of second ("showChart").when I didn't apply condition both display together .but when I apply condition .chart stop displaying why?

Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/6MYYge8mhHUJt0JFEEk5?p=preview

```
$scope.showChart=function(){
    $scope.isshowTable=false;
}
$scope.showTable=function(){
    $scope.isshowTable=true;
}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/W3wG7ug9uMbZFgI9GLu9?p=preview

you just set your closing `div` tag wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is incorrect, as your chart div is a child of the table div.
Update your html to:

```
  <div ng-show='isshowTable'>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat='n in data'>
      <div class="col-xs">
        <div class="box">{{n.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs">
        <div class="box">{{n.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs">
        <div class="box">{{n.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


 <div ng-show='!isshowTable'>
   <chart value="basicAreaChart" type="area" height="400"></chart>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you are correct but there is problem is answer

Comment: please  check this in http://plnkr.co/edit/W3wG7ug9uMbZFgI9GLu9?p=preview .In full screen mode ..you will observe that chart is not taking full width ..why ??

Comment: when you display chart alone it takes full width ..but  when you do show and hide it will not take full width

Comment: You are adding additional questions / issues to your original question. The full width issue is related to highchart settings and NOT the original angularjs question. I will answer though.  http://jsfiddle.net/dL3zynpw/  you need to set you the renderTo property of the highChart and then create an id for the parent with width:100% http://plnkr.co/edit/B1mt7wLJulSfJVGV39cW?p=preview